# Elasticsearch Not Returning Document By Field Name

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

Elasticsearch newb here.  I seem to be having an issue selecting documents by a certain field.  It feels like a corrupt index to me, but I'm not sure.

Here is a document that I can retrieve, and get the fields `event.type` and `event.accountId`:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/events-2015.04.08/event/AUyYpkl-r99VdGrSLpIX?pretty=1&fields=event.type,event.accountId'
{
  "_index" : "events-2015.04.08",
  "_type" : "event",
  "_id" : "AUyYpkl-r99VdGrSLpIX",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "fields" : {
    "event.type" : [ "USER_LOGIN" ],
    "event.accountId" : [ 10399 ]
  }
}
```

Notice the `event.type: USER_LOGIN`.  Now I want to find all documents that have this field/value combination:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/events-2015.04.08/_search?q=event.type:USER_LOGIN&pretty=1'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

No results.  I can find the document by `event.accountId` though:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/events-2015.04.08/_search?q=event.accountId:10399&pretty=1'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "events-2015.04.08",
      "_type" : "event",
      "_id" : "AUyYpkjCr99VdGrSLpIW",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source": {...}
    }, {
      "_index" : "events-2015.04.08",
      "_type" : "event",
      "_id" : "AUyYpkl-r99VdGrSLpIX",  # <-- This is the doc I want
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source": {...}
    } ]
  }
}
```

So is this field corrupt or something?  How do I check?  I expect to be able to find this document by `event.type`.

**UPDATE**

The document is being indexed with the SQS plugin to Logstash.  Here is the relevant part of `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
  sqs {
    queue => "the_queue"
    region => "us-west-2"
    type => "event"
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "Message"
    target => "event"
    remove_field => [ "Message" ]
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { "Type" => "EventType" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "Timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide the mapping, no index command used  and no the original document indexed. Anyway I think it's because `type` is kind of reserved word. Did you try to change this field's name to something else?

Comment: Not sure why the mapping or index command are important.  The fact that I am able to search for the document with one field but not another seemed like the crux of the matter.  I'll try changing the name of the field, though, and respond here.  I'll also update the question with details of how the document was indexed.

Comment: The mapping does matter.  If the field is `index: none`, you can't search by it.

Comment: I see, thank you.  As mentioned, I'm very new to elasticsearch.  I was just using logstash to index the documents, and didn't even know about the index mapping.  Anyway, it appears to be fixed by changing `event.type` to `EventType`.  @dragoste if you want to submit an answer, I'll accept.